# ajax setInterval efficiency

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, database

I am using `setInterval` to run ajax in order to retrieve data from a database as close to real time as possible (every second). For now I have small amounts of data being pulled from the `meeting_minutes_queries.php` so there is no lag or glitches. I want to expand this code to multiple div containers on the same page creating multiple db connections. This seems very inefficient and possibly even dangerous. Is there a more efficient way to go about this process?

AJAX CODE:

```
setInterval(function(){
  function update_tb(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "meeting_minutes_queries.php",
      async: false,
      success: function(result){
        $(".slide_content1").fadeIn('slow').html(result);
      }
    }).responseText;
  }
  $(function(){
    update_tb();
  });
}, 1000);
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Well you could use node.js, it will speed up your application tremendously!

Comment: Consider using web sockets.

Comment: You should really just create a function and call it recursively with setTimout. Dont use setInterval()

Comment: You could trigger the next request in the callback of the ajax request (in case some requests take longer than expected...)

Comment: I really just wanting to request new data from the db. Would web socket or node.js have this capability? And if so where could I find samples of this code as I am not familiar with this style of coding @jorge

Comment: @Rob you say you wish to request new data, but all i see you doing is requesting all data. If you were only requesting new data, this wouldn't be so bad, and could easily be adapted to use long-polling which is far better than requesting all data, or even just new data every second.

Comment: @kevin Yes I request all data every second. But I made my php script to only post if there is a difference from the the last request using session variables. Still probably inefficient. I think I will head in long polling direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is.

You can use [Long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) or [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

With slow poll you run a request and the server will keep the connection open indefinitely until it has something to say (e.g. in PHP sleep a lot and once you got a result, answer and be done).

With web sockets you have even more possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    update_tb();
  }, 1000);

  function update_tb(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "meeting_minutes_queries.php",
      async: false,
      success: function(result){
        $(".slide_content1").fadeIn('slow').html(result);
      }
    }).responseText;
  }

});
```